# Replace with dynamic variable in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm getting stuck at this problem, which is

I have an array like this:

```
$array = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'email' => john@gmail.com
];
```

And a string sample like this:

```
$string = 'Hi [[name]], your email is [[email]]';
```

The problem is obvious, replace name with `John` and email with `john@gmail.com`.

What i attempted:

```
//check if $string has [[ ]] pattern

$stringHasBrackets = preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/i', $string,  $matchOutput);

if ($stringHasBrackets) {

    foreach ($matchOutput[1] as $matchOutputKey => $stringToBeReplaced) {

        if (array_key_exists($stringToBeReplaced, $array)) {

            $newString = preg_replace("/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/i",
                            $array[$stringToBeReplaced],
                            $string);

        }
    }
}
```

Which led me to a new string like this:

```
Hi john@gmail.com, your email is john@gmail.com
```

Makes sense because that's what the pattern is for, but not what I wanted.

How can I solve this? I thought of using a variable in the pattern but don't know how to do it. I've read about preg_replace_callback but also don't really know how to implement it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  may use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'];
$string = 'Hi [[name]], your email is [[email]]';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(.*?)]]/', function ($m) use ($array) {
        return isset($array[$m[1]]) ? $array[$m[1]] : $m[0]; 
    }, $string);
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Du9r56).

**Details**

- `'/\[\[(.*?)]]/'` matches `[[...]]` substrings putting what is inside the brackets into Group 1
- `$m` holds the match object
- `use ($array)` allows the callback to access `$array` variable
- `isset($array[$m[1]])` checks if there is a value corresponding to the found key in the `$array` variable. If it is found, the value is returned, else, the found match is pasted back.

Comment: Nice answer +1 @DuongNguyen But because running regex is pretty expensive operation . i would include a if to check if the string contains a replace templates checking on `[[` and `]]` see demo https://ideone.com/K4hKmJ .. Nicer would be offcource to make a function

Comment: Thanks. Will do a research on preg_replace_callback and get back to you if this works.

@RaymondNijland I checked the string with preg_match_all, is it alright?

Comment: "I checked the string with preg_match_all, is it alright?" @DuongNguyen `preg_match_all` still uses regexes now you start up two regex engines.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace` accepts arrays as regex and replacement so you can use this simpler approach:

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'];
$string = 'Hi [[name]], your email is [[email]]';

// create array of regex using array keys
$rearr = array_map(function($k) { return '/\[\[' . $k . ']]/'; },
         array_keys($array));

# pass 2 arrays to preg_replace
echo preg_replace($rearr, $array, $string) . '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
Hi John, your email is john@gmail.com
```

[PHP Code Demo](https://eval.in/1049455)

Comment: Gotta do another research on using array_map :D

Comment: `array_map` is used to convert each key into regex. So `name` becomes `/\[\name]]/`

Comment: @bobblebubble: You're right, `array_values` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
$array = ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'];
$string = 'Hi [[name]], your email is [[email]]';
$stringHasBrackets = preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/i', $string,  $matchOutput);

if ($stringHasBrackets) {
    $newString = $string;
    foreach ($matchOutput[1] as $matchOutputKey => $stringToBeReplaced) {
        if (array_key_exists($stringToBeReplaced, $array)) {
            $newString = preg_replace("/\[\[$stringToBeReplaced\]\]/i", $array[$stringToBeReplaced], $newString);
        }
    }
    echo $newString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. I'm not a regex wizard but how did you know where to put the variable?

Comment: @DuongNguyen, Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think here more simply would be to use `str_replace` function, like:

```
$array = [
          'name' => 'John',
          'email' => 'john@gmail.com'
          ];

$string = 'Hi [[name]], your email is [[email]]';
$string = str_replace(array_map(function ($v) {return "[[{$v}]]";}, 
                      array_keys($array)), $array, $string);
echo $string;
```

Updated for $array to be "untouchable"

Comment: This can be much simpler than using regex, but I'm not allowed to touch the array, and array_keys returns an array, so can I somehow concatenate [[ and ]] to it?
Also, I want to replace array_keys($array) in the string with array values.

Comment: see updated version - in this case we need `array_map` also. And yes - it searches in string for modified keys and replaces with array values

Comment: Thank you Agnius!