# Passing value to view template in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I know that my question is elementary in php, but I can't find any resource to solve it.
For sake of simplicity, I brief my problem with a simple code.

I want to separate php and html files. So I creates a file named: view.php

```
<?php
global $var;

?>
<html>
<body>

<p>
Variable value is:
    <?php  $var ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have another file that uses this template: call.php

```
<?php



function call(){
global $var;
    $var='111';
    require_once 'view.php';
}


call();
```

The problem is that the variable does not pass from call.php to view.php.

This code prints a simple html as follow:

Variable value is:

As you can see, the variable value has not printed here.

Please assume that the view.php is a large html template that would be populated with numbers of variables.
So, I want to controller and view be  as separated as possible.(I don't want to echo html directly)

how can I do that?

I tested the above code, but without success

Comment: You need to echo your variable - `<?php echo $var; ?>`

Comment: You also don't need the `global`, since the variable is in scope even without it. (In general, for the sake of sanity, look for solutions that don't depend on global variables.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't imagine how I missed this obvious mistake. I was baffled for a day or two. It just solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you wanted to separate HTML entirely into `.html` files, and tokenize variables, then please see my answer to [Simple templating system with {{field}} in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863197/4630325).

Comment: Thank you @MarkusAO for your reply. This is an awesome feature than can be implemented for separating html part completely. But in some occasion, maybe the `.php` is the preferred solution. For example, in this project, I use `foreach` in some part of the code to output dynamic view.